# Changing QGIS back to English

Tags: qgis, internationalization

When I booted up my windows machine this morning my menus had switch from English to what I think may be Russian and I can't read the menu options. I have tried unistalling, rebooting and then reinstalling but this has not helped.

How do I change them back?