# Change language of QGIS Browser to English

Tags: qgis, gui, internationalization, qgis-browser

I want to change the language of QGIS Browser graphical user interface (GUI) to English. I know how to change the language of QGIS GUI itself from (Settings->Options->Locale), but that does not change the language of QGIS Browser. I also tried to change the language of QGIS Browser from OSGeo4W Shell with the following commands:

1. `qgis-browser --lang=en`
2. `qgis-browser --lang en`
3. `qgis-browser --lang en_US`
4. `qgis-browser.bat --lang en_US`
5. `qgis-browser.bat --lang=en_US`

But unfortunately none of the above commands succeeded to change the language of QGIS Browser.

Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: you can test [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44622/how-to-change-qgis-back-to-english) . just back up your registry first before any change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to force localization to english. It's an ugly way but it works...

Go to (QGIS_DIR)\apps\qgis\i18n, make a backup folder and move all files into that folder. That will force QGIS and QGIS Browser to be displayed in their original language, in this case in English. ;)

In case you want another language just restore it from the backup folder to the i18n folder.

Comment: It worked, thank you. But I think it will be better if QGIS Developer team can   also put control to change the language of QGIS Browser GUI similar to QGIS Desktop from (Settings->Options->Locale).